# Is Hanbook for CSIRTs still relevant learning material today?

Tags: incident-response, soc

The question is pretty self-explanatory. Is this book relevant today considering it has been published some time ago? If anyone has read it could you answer what are some things that have changed and what stayed the same considering best CSIRT practices?